# Два интерфейса одного Андроид-приложения

Tags: android

Есть два типа пользователей (сервис и заказчики). При введении логина приложение должно определить к какому типу пользователь относится и открыть соответствующий интерфейс. У заказчиков должно отображаться меню, а у сервиса лист заказов. Помогите с решением этой задачи. Как его можно реализовать?

Comment: Сделать активити входа, в кторой определять, кто вошел и по результату запускать одну из двух активити - сервиса или заказчика?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Необходимо создать три Activity: LoginActivity, UserActivity, BossActivity.
2. При запуске приложения должно запускаться LoginActivity.
3. В нем при нажатии кнопки "Логин" происходит авторизация пользователя в зависимости от того, к какой категории он принадлежит.
4. В зависимости от результата из LoginActivity посылается Intent либо в UserActivity, либо в BossActivity.

На самом деле вопрос достаточно общий, краткий ответ на него дать невозможно, поэтому посоветовал бы в принципе изучить хотя бы немного основ андроида самому. Для начала подойдут вот эти материалы (написано по эклипсу, но по ним можно прекрасно все понимать и в андроид-студии).

1. Тут описан минимум про механизм Intent:
   http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/59-urok-22-intent-intent-filter-context-teorija.html
2. Тут показан пример применения Intent на практике:
   http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/64-urok-26-intent-filter-praktika.html
3. Для авторизации пользователя скорей всего может понадобиться база данных, можно посмотреть уроки 34-39:
   http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html

Большинство уроков написаны понятно и актуально даже сейчас, поэтому в принципе можно почитать и другие материалы с этого сайта. При необходимости "влезть в детали" или обратиться к истокам лучшим вариантом будет обратиться к урокам от гугла, это, наверное, лучшее, что можно найти в сети:
https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал читать не статьи в интернете, а книги. Это качественно иной уровень. Одна книга Б. Харди ответит на **все** вопросы начинаеющего разработчика в едином, целостном изложении. Аналогичный объем знаний и, главное, навыков в организации общей структуры приложения по разрозненным урокам в интернете не получишь вовсе, даже если они собраны в одну кучку, как на startandroid или у Климова. По урокам можно быстро вспомнить основные конструкции и тп.